# Java Socket или WebSocket?

Tags: android, сокет, websocket

Не знаю, что выбрать для реализации чата. Решил спросить здесь. Вопрос состоит не в том, чем отличаются эти две технологии и т.п. Спрашиваю конструктивно про производительность, какие-либо бенчмарки и опыт работы с тем и тем. Или же не нужно сравнивать эти два способа коммуникации? Будьте добры, поделитесь опытом!

Comment: WebSocket. https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websocket-multiple-users-encoders-decoders-dogs/

Comment: Спасибо за тутор! То есть вы считаете, что нужно выбирать вебсокеты?   Не могли бы поподробнее рассказать почему?

Comment: WebSocket заточен для работы в вебе то бишь там уже реализован сервер как таковой, а обычные сокеты используются в десктоп приложениях в основном или же просто для получения информации. В случае использования обычных сокетов Вам надо будет писать очень много чего, тогда как в вебсокетах уже написано за Вас.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Приму к сведению

Comment: @vladey_slavoy если у тебя есть сервер с ws, то по ws с этим сервером может работать и браузер и приложение андроид. к примре можно организовать трекер, андроид отправляет gps координаты на сервер, а браузер отображает их на карет(гугла или яндекса) и асё это в реальном времени